# Unique keys set not working on Drift Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor, drift, moor

I have this table with a set of unique keys {id, order}. The problem is that when I create a new part in a different order, it automatically replaces the entire part. If I had the part with id 1 associated with order 5, when I create a new part, which will have id 1, in order 3 for example, it deletes the part that had been associated with order number 5 to create the new one in order 3.

When I create a new part I use the insertOrReplace mode because otherwise it says that already exists a part with that constraints. Even if it doesn't.

I do something wrong? What should I do? Thanks.

```
@DataClassName('Part')
class Parts extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer()();
  TextColumn get startDate => text().withLength(min: 17, max: 17)();
  TextColumn get endDate => text().withLength(min: 0, max: 17)();
  TextColumn get observations => text()();
  IntColumn get order =>
      integer().customConstraint('NOT NULL REFERENCES orders (id)')();

  @override
  List<Set<Column>> get uniqueKeys => [
        {id, order}
      ];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. The output of what you expect and what actually happens would help.